# Problems with Application identifier, XNA 4.0 for Windows Phone 8, Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8, xna-4.0

I have been developing a game using xna 4.0 that I started developing using a Windows Phone 7.1 phone. When I used the Windows Phone 7.1 phone that I first started developing the game with, there was no problems at all to debug using the phone. At this time I was using visual Studio 2010.

However I recently bought a Windows Phone 8 and now want to continue to develop the game, and I would like to debug the game on the Windows Phone 8. I have therefore downloaded Visual Studio 2012 and Windows Phone SDK 8.0, and have now been trying to deploy the game on the Windows Phone 8 device.

However when I try to do so I get an error message that I haven't found any solution for yet. The error message is:

Application identifier 30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E is not a valid application identifier.

However when I search my entire project for this identifier, no matches are found.

I found [this thread](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/17/topics/18210) when searching for a solution.

I changed the row for assembly: Guid to the suggested [assembly: Guid("$guid1$")] , but this made no difference.

If you know any solution or tips that can help me find a solution it would be highly appreciated.

Regards, Viktor

Answer (score 0):

Have your try to upgrade? And before you do that make sure that the Windows Phone 7.1 version project has a reference to System.Core.dll and mscorlib.dll before the upgrade.

EDIT

To upgrade/convert try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207030(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Is it possible to upgrade XNA 4.0 games that targets Windows Phone 7.1 to target Windows Phone 8.0? If so how do I do so? 
It would be great if it is possible, but the information I can find unfortunately seems to state that it isn't possible:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207003(v=vs.105).aspx

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207030(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @Tigerstrom it does say that you should be able to use 7.1. Otherwise you can try recreate the whole game step by step. But that's not fun.

Comment: Yea I guess recreating the game is the worst case scenario, would be great if I could avoid it though.
Just to try I started a new blank xna 4.0 project for Windows Phone 7.1 in Visual Studio 2010, and then tried deploy the game on my windows 8 phone in Visual Studio 2012. It worked perfectly so I guess there has to be some problem with my code, I just don't know what the problem is though. If it helps anyone to understand what the problem is I have been using Windows Game State Management for Windows Phone and IsolatedStorage with XmlSerializer in the game.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was, the name of one of the pictures included as content, was spelled with a foreign letter.